# same id given to various btns

Tags: javascript, html

I recently visited a website and was checking through its html code and found that two different inputs of type radio were given same id, how can it be possible? I tried to check the radio buttons but I was only able to check the first button how do I check the other buttons using javascript if both are given same id
[image radio buttons on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qynbB.jpg)

[image of html code where same id given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG47H.jpg)

Comment: You can't access multiple elements with the same ID from javascript. The developer of the website has made an error.

Comment: both have different values so you could use that as the selector

Comment: What about if you try to get all the input fields with name and then try to select specific one with the index?

Comment: As per the [ask] guide (which you are encouraged to read before posting) please do not include images of code. Code is text and should be provided as text, it's much easier that way for everyone trying to help with your question. And the screenshot really has no bearing at all on the question in this case. You can [edit] the question to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

> elements of type radio are generally used in radio
> groups—collections of radio buttons describing a set of related
> options.
>
> Only one radio button in a given group can be selected at the same
> time. Radio buttons are typically rendered as small circles, which are
> filled or highlighted when selected.

Every element on your document is expected to have a unique `id` value for its `id` property otherwise odd things would happen when trying to select those elements using a css selector both in styles and js (to cite one).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme) there's an in depth discussion on SO for example for further reference.

But for sure they are meant to be grouped using the same `name` attribute value to hint which group is expected to have a mutually exclusive checked status and to converge to the same GET/POST parameter, named like that `name` property and having as value the value of the only radio selected in its group, when its form will be submitted.